# Jquery slideToggle headers move when another one is click

Tags: jquery

I have three headers that are inline-block div’s using slideToggle.

(this is one example of the three divs)

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="links">Portfolio</div>
    <div class="descriptions"> this is an example </div>    
</div>
```

If I click on one of the headers it will display the info beneath it. What I’m looking for is for none of the headers to move when one is clicked. Please view my website to see my example. http://mast.salemstate.edu/itc18244/Portfolio/index2.html Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You **have** to post all relevant code in question itself

Comment: I wouldn't want to overwhelm the viewer looking at all the could I could post in here, which is why I have a site with all the source code on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your site I believe I have a solution. The problem with your site is flow of elements when they are being rendered. When on of your divs that are being toggled visible they need X amount of room due to the flow of the page. Therefore, moving the other elements on the page. You need to take the toggled divs out of the normal rendering flow. I achieved this by setting their `position` to `absolute` then doing some math to give them a `relative` position. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0fm3b3pa/

Comment: You got it! At this point I would only want one header to display at a time, because if you click on more than one they will all display.

Comment: You can use the `.css()` function to hide on click. ex. http://jsfiddle.net/0fm3b3pa/1/

Comment: Great! that worked too, I saw what the change it did, but what .css() function did you edit?

Comment: I added a line of code to the top of the `on` function

Comment: Roger that! appreciate your help :)